# Log parsing with python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python. What I want to do is to make a log file readable.

For now what I have is a way to read and write a file..

For parsing the log line I use this code:

```
if 'EXAMPLE LINE IN LOG FILE WITH extra info tag=on' in line:              
   output_file.write(datestring + " Device was turned on" + "\n")
```

Not very pythonic but it works for me.

Now what I want to do is write `Divices was turned off` if the line in the log says `tag=off`.
I can simply copy the code again like this:

```
if 'EXAMPLE LINE IN LOG FILE WITH extra info tag=off' in line:              
   output_file.write(datestring + " Device was turned off" + "\n")
```

But that is not very nice and it is more easy editing in the future.

Can someone help my on my way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I kept this one simple and easy for me to understand:

```
        if 'ScreenLockReceiver; tag=on' in line:              
           output_file.write(datestring + " Screen was activated." + "\n")
        if 'ScreenLockReceiver; tag=off' in line:              
           output_file.write(datestring + " Screen was deactivated." + "\n")
        if 'ScreenLockReceiver; tag=unlock' in line:              
           output_file.write(datestring + " Device was unlocked." + "\n")
```

Thanks for the help! Understanding a bit more!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Alexandre's answer, if every line includes tag=on or tag=off then a simple if-else should do the job:

```
file_string = datestring + " Device was turned" 
if "tag=on" in line:
    file_string += " on\n"
else:
    file_string += " off\n"
output_file.write(file_string)
```

You can also tidy your code up a little using f-strings:

```
file_string = f"{datestring} Device was turned" 
if "tag=on" in line:
    file_string += " on\n"
else:
    file_string += " off\n"
output_file.write(file_string)
```

Using f-strings is a way to quickly concatenate loads of different variables in a string, just be sure to place any variables inside of the {} characters. This has the added benefit of automatically converting anything to string-type.

You mentioned that you're a beginner, so something else you may find helpful is using a context manager to handle your file operations.

```
output_file = open('output_file.txt', 'w')
output_file.write(file_string)
output_file.close()
```

Is the same as:

```
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_string)
```

Using a context manager will automatically close the files for you, and has the added benefit of making your code look much cleaner. Putting everything together:

```
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        file_string = f"{datestring} Device was turned" 
        if "tag=on" in line:
            file_string += " on\n"
        else:
            file_string += " off\n"
    output_file.write(file_string)
```

Hopefully that helps! I've written an article on opening and closing files properly if you'd like to learn more:

https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-close-file/

I've also got another one which explains f-strings in more detail (see the solution at the end of cause 1):

https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-str/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

If every line of your log contains either `tag=on` or `tag=off`, you could do this:

```
output_file.write(datestring + " Device was turned " + "on" if "tag=on" in line else "off" + "\n")
```

The `if` is now directly inside the `write()` statement and dynamically changes depending on the line.

Edit:

Since you can have multiple values for `tag`, you can no longer only use `if/else` as I suggested.

What you could do now is check for the value of `tag` with Alfie's solution using an [elif](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) statement.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: I think I should be more specific. The log file I want to pase is a Whatsapp logfile.
And the logline i want to parse is:   ScreenLockReceiver; tag=on; locked=true; oldLocked=true. Now the locked and oldLocked I dont care about. But the tag can have 3 values. on, off or unlocked.

Comment: Can you provide examples? You can replace any sensitive information, we just need to see what a line can look like.

Comment: A line can look like this:

ScreenLockReceiver; tag=on; locked=true; oldLocked=true.

Where the tag= can be on off or unlocked.

Comment: Then what Alfie and I suggested should work. Try either code and accept the corresponding answer if it works.

Comment: It works if you only have the tag on or off. I have the tag on / off / unlocked.

Comment: @jerry99 I made an edit to answer your question more precisely.