# Whatsapp logparsing python

Tags: python

I want to parse a whatsapp logfile.
In one line I have: conversation/window-focus-changed 0648@s.whatsapp.net true of conversation/window-focus-changed 0648@s.whatsapp.net false.

I want to parse this line to:

Conversation of user 0648@s.whatsapp.net was opened if true or closed if false.
Now the user is variable offcouse.

Right now i have a code that sort of works.

```
if 'conversation/window-focus-changed' in line:
           output_file.write(datestring + " conversation of user " + line[line.find("@s.whatsapp.net") - 4:] + "\n")
```

This way I get this output in the file.

2020-12-12 08:35:01.132 conversation of user 0648@s.whatsapp.net true

but I want the true to be opend or closed.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try using the answers in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362127/log-parsing-with-python/68362290#68362290) to solve this problem. It is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

This one was a bit harder. The log line is as follow:

1999-01-01 08:35:01.132 LL_I D [2:main] conversation/window-focus-changed 0000@s.whatsapp.net true or
1999-01-01 08:35:14.056 LL_I D [2:main] conversation/window-focus-changed 0000@s.whatsapp.net false

used this code:

```
            conversation_user = line[line.find("@s.whatsapp.net") - 4:]
        if "@s.whatsapp.net true" in line:
            open_close = " was opend."
        else:
            open_close = "was closed."           
        if 'conversation/window-focus-changed' in line:                    
           output_file.write(datestring + " Conversation with Whatsapp user" + (conversation_user[:-5]) + open_close + "\n")
```

And got this result:
1999-01-01 08:35:01.132 Conversation with Whatsapp user 0000@s.whatsapp.net was opend.
1999-01-01 08:35:14.056 Conversation with Whatsapp user 0000@s.whatsapp.net was closed.

Its ugly code I know, but It got the job done.